# Collapsing/contracting an expanded comment section

Tags: feature-request, comments

Sometimes a question or answer has 20 or more comments under it and are quite
usefull. Because of that I tend to expand them. after reading them however I'd
like to contract/collapse the section again as it takes a lot of space.

## Rephrased question

I would like to see an option to "hide comments" after selecting "show x more
comments". I know it is possible to reset the comment section by refreshing
the page, but I don't think this is the way it should be done.

Is this a reasonable feature for the Stackexchange network?

**Example**

Let's say there are two comment sections I have expanded, the
first I want to keep open, the second I want to collapse again. The way I
would do it now is: refresh the page and expand the first comment section. The
way I would do it with a collapse option is just collapse the second section.
It takes one step less.

In big O notation, I believe the first method would be O(n-1) and the second
method O(1), given I have at least two comment sections open and want to close
one.

## Original question

I don't see an option to "hide comments" like I do for "show x more
comments".

Is it simpely not possiblity or am I missing something?

Comment: This feature does not exist currently. If you want it, you could rephrase the question as a feature-request. But, you could just refresh the page! It hides the comments and takes you back to the same place on the page...

Comment: What is the use-case that refreshing the page does not satisfy? (I'm not suggesting there could not be one; but this request would be more valuable with an explanation of what makes the requested feature useful.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have made an edit with an explenation.